# Network aware snitches

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

What are the network aware snitches in Cassandra? They have specified that NetworkToplogy can only be used with network aware snitches. So what are the snitches that can use NetworkTopology?

Answer (score 3):

Check the [list of snitches](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchesAbout_c.html) available for Cassandra.  I believe the only non "network aware" switch is the [SimpleSnitch](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchSimple_c.html).  From the descriptions given, all of the other snitches should be "network aware."

As for the [EC2Snitch](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2_t.html) supporting multiple datacenters, this is from the DataStax documentation:

> Use with Amazon EC2 in a single region.
>
> Use the EC2Snitch for simple cluster deployments on Amazon EC2 where
>   all nodes in the cluster are within a single region.
>
> The region name is treated as the data center name and availability
>   zones are treated as racks within a data center. For example, if a
>   node is in the us-east-1 region, us-east is the data center name and 1
>   is the rack location. (Racks are important for distributing replicas,
>   but not for data center naming.) Because private IPs are used, this
>   snitch does not work across multiple regions.
>
> If you are using only a single data center, you do not need to specify
>   any properties.
>
> If you need multiple data centers, set the dc_suffix options in the
>   cassandra-rackdc.properties file.

Comment: Are you sure about it. EC2Snitch didn't work for me with NetworkTopology.

Comment: The EC2Snitch still works with the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file for datacenter/rack/node definition.  It is intended to be used for sigle-region deployments, but can still support multiple DC and rack definitions.

Comment: EC2SNITCH supports multi DC? Think you are wrong on that as they communicate on private IP.

Comment: I wanted to know about network aware snitches since I was not able to operate on a keyspace with NetworkTopology. I kept getting one or more nodes unavailable. I will checking my nodetool status anyway later on but I doubt if cassandra really assigns the datacenter name when using EC2snitch

Comment: EC2Snitch considers racked properties? I doubt that too. In general , it auto detects. Only EC2multiregion snitch uses it.

Comment: @Ananth Note that the EC2Snitch is designed to work with the private IPs designated as the `listen_address` and `rpc_address`.  I have seen instances of trouble with node communication with EC2, and it is often traced back to improper IP configuration.

Comment: Those configurations were fine. As I told, I have been administering cassandra for the past two years on dedicated servers. My problem is usage of EC2Snitch. It's stated that it automatically detects datacenter name bt I doubt if it's happening as it's important for NetworkTopology

Comment: The EC2Snitch will, by default, map the datacenter name to the EC2 Region and since it only supports one region it will not support multi-dc -- unless it is configured manually in cassandra-rackdc.properties. You can always verify the name of your DC using nodetool status.

Comment: @Aaron Nice explanation Aaron. Let us consider if I am having a cluster of 4 nodes in amazon EC2 instances, what will happen if I configured snitch to default property of SimpleSnitch? In listen_address, rpc_address I have configured own private IP address in all the nodes. What is the significance of such configuration? Whether it will cause any trouble?